# document.getElementById('dvFile').innerHTML += txt;

Tags: javascript

document.getElementById('dvFile').innerHTML += txt; is not working internet explorer 7

Comment: Not Working = ? any error messages?

Comment: its saying unknown run time error

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066443/ie-innerhtml-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your object called **dvFile** is wrong type for innerHTML. **dvFile** must not be represented any kind of input.

Check following valid script.

```
<script>
function setTimeout_Testing()
{
count = 1;
document.getElementById("writeMe").innerHTML += count;
}
setTimeout("setTimeout_Testing();", 1000);
</script>

<div id="writeMe"></div>
```

http://www.ppshein.net/index.cfm/2010/10/18/different-between-settimeout-and-setinterval

Answer (score 1):

You can only add html with `+`:

```
document.getElementById('dvFile').innerHTML = txt;
```

If you want previous html to be preserved, you can try this way:

```
document.getElementById('dvFile').innerHTML = document.getElementById('dvFile').innerHTML + txt;
```

Comment: with more detail, you can find your answer in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066443/ie-innerhtml-error

Answer (score -1):

First off you don't have a real question here. It's a statement at best. A bug report maybe.

If you want help you should provide details.

Your problem is probably because you are trying to set `innerHTML` of a [`<table>`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239832) element or a[`<select>`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228). Because in **IE**:

> The innerHTML property of the TABLE,
>   TFOOT, THEAD, and TR elements are
>   read-only. *Q239832*

Things you can do include:

- using DOM methods to add content (`insertRow`, `insertCell`)
- using a workaround with a wrapper element

**[[Demo](http://jsbin.com/obape3/4/)]**

```
var txt = "<tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td></tr>";
var table = document.getElementById('table_id');
var temp  = document.createElement("div");
temp.innerHTML = "<table><tbody>" + txt + "</tbody></table>";
table.appendChild(temp.firstChild.firstChild);
```