# IE not displaying strings with HTML tags passed to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

I am passing a string containing HTML tags (center, ul, etc) to a function which then places it in a div, span or p innerHTML.  This works great in all browsers but IE, which displays nothing.  I tracked the problem the the tags, because plain text does display in IE.

I am using IE 9.
The code is a little long for posting, but here is the idea:

```
str='<center>Some text</center>';
displayText('divId',str);
function displayText(id,str)
{ document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=str; }
```

Sorry everyone.  I found that I could not set the innerHTML of a [P] element.  I changed it to a [span] and it worked.

Comment: Can you add some sample code with input output, and also specify which version of IE you are trying this against? IE is a strange beast. There are differences between each version of IE, which makes the life of a web developer very difficult.

Comment: Make sure the html you try to insert is valid html

Comment: That example code, if "divId" is **really** the "id" value for a `<div>`, will work in IE.

Comment: Your recently posted example works even in IE 5.5: http://jsbin.com/esado5/

Comment: *"I found that I could not set the innerHTML of a [P] element"* You may accept an answer then.

Comment: Sure, how do I "accept and answer"

Answer (score 3):

`innerHTML` is not a good idea (or needs a workaround) for `<table>`, `<select>`, `<p>` elements. This is a [known](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228) [limitation](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html) in older versions [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also see this question [IE innerHTML error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066443/ie-innerhtml-error).

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I experimented with the tags and got my answer. I really should have known, had the same problem with tables but found that I could do it with the TD tag.

Answer (score 0):

Glad that you found a solution..

You should consider using [jquery](http://jquery.com/). Then you don't have to worry about all the cross browser implementations & instead focus on adding/enhancing functionality & user experience on your site/application.